# Quotient group isomorphic to $A_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

> Let $G=GL(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$. Prove that $H/Z(G) \cong A_4$, where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$ and $H=\{A \in G \mid \det (A)=1\}=\ker (\det)$.

We know that $|H|=\dfrac{|G|}{|\ker(\det)|}=\dfrac{48}{2}=24$, and
$Z(G)=\left\{\lambda I \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{F}_{3}^{*}\right\}=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{ll}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{array}\right)\right\}$.

So we have that $|H/Z(G)|=|A_4|$. At this point, if we find an injective homomorphism between $H/Z(G)$ and $A_4$, we can conclude that is an isomorphism. The problem if I don't know how $H$ is made, and consequently how the quotient is made. So, how can I build this homomorphism?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$SL_2(\mathbb Z_3)/Z(SL_2(\mathbb Z_3)) \cong \mathbb A_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325327/sl-2-mathbb-z-3-zsl-2-mathbb-z-3-cong-mathbb-a-4). As $H=\operatorname{SL}(2,\Bbb F_3)$ and $\Bbb F_3$ is just fancy name of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ I think you should find there everything you need.